# Codename One - Storing sensitive data

Tags: java, security, codenameone

Saying **sensitive data** i mean:

- Certificates
- Passwors
- other private secrets

**Question 1**. Is there any way for **third-party applications** to access this information, stored using `Storage` class?

**Question 2**. I suppose using `FileSystemStorage` is **not safe** at all. Is it right?

**Question 3**. What is the safest way to store sensitive data in *Codename One*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Codename offers an encryption for your sensitive data with the introduction of [EncrytedStorage](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/seamless-storage-encryption.html). Although, it requires you to install BouncyCastle cn1lib for it to work. You can find this lib under **CodenameOne Extensions** when you right-click on your project and go to **CodenameOne Settings.**

FileSystemStorage is safe but not totally secure and yes, could be accessed by another App if the app knows your App's Storage path which is usually possible on rooted android devices.

Comment: Great answer, just to clarify a small point. `Storage` is "possibly private" and it's app isolation is implementation dependent and not guaranteed which is why we have the encrypted storage option.